# How to choose a specific weight from a font family using fontspec and XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I have installed an open-type font on my OS and would like to use in a LaTeX document using XeLaTeX.

It works fine, but when I define my font family like this:

```
\ifxetex
  \newfontfamily{\neosans}{NeoSans} 
\else
\fi
```

When I then use `\selectfont\neosans`it just selects the Regular version of that font. However, I would like to use the Light version!

Even if I write `\newfontfamily{\neosans}{NeoSans-Light}` or `\newfontfamily{\neosans}{NeoSans Light}` it still chooses the Regular version.

The specifications of the font I would like to use looks as follows (in Danish, though):

[image: Link to image]

### My question is

How do use the Light version of the font?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't have NeoSans, but experimented with another font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\os}{Open Sans}
\newfontfamily{\osl}[UprightFont={* Light}]{Open Sans}
\begin{document}
{Normal: \os Open Sans\par}
{Light: \osl Open Sans Light\par}
\end{document}
```

You see that the second line indeed chooses the light version.

[image]

Notice that `\selectfont` is not needed (and does nothing).

In your case you probably want to also change the italic and bold version:

```
\newfontfamily{\neosans}
  [Ligatures=TeX, % recommended
   UprightFont={* Light},
   ItalicFont={* Light Italic},
   BoldFont={* Medium},
   BoldItalicFont={* Medium Italic}]
  {NeoSans}
```

If you want that NeoSans is used as the standard sans serif font, then instead of `\newfontfamily{\neosans}` write `\setsansfont`:

```
\setsansfont
  [Ligatures=TeX, % recommended
   UprightFont={* Light},
   ItalicFont={* Light Italic},
   BoldFont={* Medium},
   BoldItalicFont={* Medium Italic}]
  {NeoSans}
```

Answer (score 9):

A lot of people will recommend against mixing multiple weights of the same font in the same document, but LaTeX does standardize font series names for Light (`{l}`), as well as `{el}`, `{ul}`, `{sb}`, `{eb}` and `{ub}`.

So, this alternative *might* (I haven’t tested it) make all the styles in your screenshot available as part of the same family.

```
\newfontfamily\neosans{NeoSans}[
  % Ligatures = ..., etc.
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic ,
  BoldFont = *-Bold ,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic ,
  FontFace = {l}{n}{*-Light},
  FontFace = {l}{it}{*-LightItalic},
  FontFace = {sb}{n}{*-Medium},
  FontFace = {sb}{it}{*-MediumItalic},
  FontFace = {eb}{n}{*-Black},
  FontFace = {eb}{it}{*-BlackItalic},
  Extention = .otf ]
```

This assumes that a font with PostScript outlines that you’re loading with `fontspec` has an `*.otf` extension.

The standard LaTeX command to select a weight other than regular or bold is, *e.g.*, `\fontseries{eb}\selectfont`.  For convenience and compatibility with a few other packages, you might define commands like the following:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sbseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ebseries}{\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texteb}{\ebseries}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ltseries}{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textlt}{\ltseries}
```

This allows you to write `\ltseries` as you would `\bfseries`, or `\texteb{foo}` like you would `\textmd{foo}`.