# How to control the boldness for both text and math formulas

Tags: bold

In the given picture I want to make the statement of the problem more bold but less the line "DM Your Answer!". ASimilarly I want to make math expressions bold but less bold than the logo of the page " Creative Math Solving" [image]

I want to make some of the text very bold, some less bold. Same for math formulas. I want to make very bold the page logo and make less bold the given conditions of the problem. Also I want to control the bold like I can create a new color in xcolor package by selecting rgb values. Same here. I want to create a new bold (like the heading boldness will be 2mm and normal letters will be 1mm)

How to do that.

Comment: The text portion of your screenshot appears to be in Times Roman, whereas the math portion is in Computer Modern, which is *much* lighter/thinner than Times Roman. I think you may achieve your objective almost automatically by employing a Times Roman-based math font.

Comment: How to do that...and also tell me how to do the selective bold as i said in the question

Comment: For multiple font weights for text, (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62603/how-to-choose-a-specific-weight-from-a-font-family-using-fontspec-and-xelatex/444875#444875) may help. For multple weights in math mode, (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228735/make-specific-math-symbols-heavier/228953#228953) may hep. Unrelated - Use @ to ping a user.